# How to count or get summary value in looping array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have data `dd($arr)` like this:

[image]

How can I sum `retweet_count` value like `233 + 2 = 235`?

Comment: Can you give us that sample instead of giving an image of it ? So we can try on your example

Comment: Use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Comment: so i want summary every retweet_count value, the value in this sample is 235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_sum and array_column.
Array_column takes one specific item column from an multidimensional array and makes a flat array of it, and array_sum sums the flat array.

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, "retweet_count")); // 235
```

edit: I see that your array is not the same all the way. You may need to use this instead to isolate the statuses.

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr["statuses"], "retweet_count")); // 235
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray){
 foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value){
  $sumArray[$id]+=$value;}
   }
   print_r($sumArray);
```

Comment: Please check this code... and try to  sum your retweet_count  value.... Hope this code help you.......

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to the answer and format it properly?

Comment: This code will loop "search_metadata" also and possibly output a wrong output. Since you sum everything the parts of the array that is not summable will create errors or notices, such as `"in"+"en"` cant be summed. And last but not least `$sumArray[$id]+=` will create a notice that `$sumArray[$id]` does not exist on the first run on every item/$id.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's usually better to provide an explanation of why and how this code helps in this case. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Please check my answers

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [gozhi] => 2
        [uzorong] => 1
        [ngangla] => 4
        [langthel] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [gozhi] => 5
        [uzorong] => 0
        [ngangla] => 3
        [langthel] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [gozhi] => 3
        [uzorong] => 0
        [ngangla] => 1
        [langthel] => 3
    )
 )
```

Comment: You can use array_walk_recursive() to get a general-case solution for your problem (the one when each inner array can possibly have unique keys).

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can use array_walk_recursive() to get a general-case solution for your problem (the 
 one when each inner array can possibly have unique keys).**

$final = array();
array_walk_recursive($input, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
$final[$key] = isset($final[$key]) ?  $item + $final[$key] : $item;
});

**Example with array_walk_recursive() for the general case**

array_sum(array_column($input, 'gozhi')); 


**Example with array_column() for the specified key**


 If you want to get the total sum of all inner arrays with the same keys (the desired 
 result that you've posted), you can do something like this (bearing in mind that the 
 first inner array must have the same structure as the others) :


  $final = array_shift($input);

  foreach ($final as $key => &$value){
  $value += array_sum(array_column($input, $key));
   }    

  unset($value);
```